# Communication between Xbee Series 1 and different RF Module(TI-CC2538)

Tags: xbee

I want to test communication between Xbee Series 1 and TI CC2538.

I built 802.15.4 protocol on CC2538 and i want to test whether it
can transmit and receive data with Xbee Series 1 through XCTU.

I tried to scan in XCTU program, but it couldn't find any device.

I set scenario that CC2538 RF chip is coordinator and Xbee S1 is a device trying to associate PAN network.

According to 802.15.4, device has to passive scan and receive beacon frame, after then, device should transmit association request mac command to coordinator which is CC2538.

How Xbee series 1 through XCTU's scan button is working ?

Does it wait for receiving Beacon frame or send beacon request or other frame ?

Is there other way to test communication between Xbee s1 and CC2538 with 802.15.4 which i built ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not trying to run ZigBee protocol on the CC2538.  The XBee Series 1 is 802.15.4 and you would need to use a Series 2 for ZigBee.

You might need to use an 802.15.4 sniffer to monitor communications to see what's happening.  Does the XBee module send a properly formatted association request?  Can you capture another CC2538 successfully joining your network, and compare it to the XBee module's attempts to do so?

Make sure that the XBee module is configured with `ATSC` (Scan Channels) set to enable whatever channel the CC2538 has established.

I know that some XBee modules support an `ATAS` (Active Scan) command that will report on beacons seen, but I'm not sure whether the Series 1 supports that command.  `ATAI` provides details on association.

Can you enable debugging on the CC2538 and have it report on the XBee module's attempts to join the network?

Comment: I had checked that Xbee module received beacon frame from CC2538 when Xbee was doing Active Scan and CC2538 had received beacon request and association request. However, when CC2538 sent a association response frame, Xbee didn't receive anything. When Xbee send a assocation request, It's src address is MAC address(64bit). So, On CC2538, I parsed association request frame and set destination address to   Xbee's MAC address. Is it right ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the CC2538, but shouldn't its network stack take care of that for you?  Are CC2538 routers able to join to your CC2538 coordinator?

Comment: I'm using 802.15.4. Is there need to use router?. In my network which i made, there are just two components. Device(Xbee) and Coordinator(CC2538)

Comment: I sometimes get confused on which features are a part of ZigBee, and which are in 802.15.4.  I use "router" to refer to a non-coordinator joining your network.  I asked about having a CC2538 join your CC2538 so you could compare the packets sent and behavior of the devices.  If a CC2538 router can't join your CC2538 coordinator's network, there's something wrong with your coordinator and you'll want to fix that first.